# G-Modules on X=G/H modules on X/H ?

Tags: equivariant, reference-request

I think it is true that $G$-equivariant sheaves on $X$ are equal to $G/H$ equivariant sheaves on $X/H$. More precisely I'm interested in the following statement:

Given an algebraic group $G$ with normal subgroup $H$ and an action of $G$ on $X$, such that the quotient $X/H$ exists as a variety and $X\rightarrow X/H$ is an $H$ principal bundle.

Then the category of $G$ equivariant 
$\mathcal{O}_X$ Modules is equivalent to the category of $G/H$ equivariant modules on the quotient.

The equivalence should be given by pullback along $X\rightarrow X/G$ in one direction and taking invariant sections in the other.

Is there a reference for this?

Comment: I don't know a reference, but it should follow from the following: (1) $G$-equivariant sheaves on X = sheaves on the quotient stack $X//G$; (2) $G/H$-equivariant sheaves on $X/H$ = sheaves on the quotient stack $(X/H)//(G/H)$; (3) $X/H = X//H$ (because of the assumptions on the action of $H$ on $X$); and finally (4) $(X//H)//(G/H) = X//G$. 

Comment: Thanks, this looks good, however I am not yet very experianced with stacks. Have you a reference for some of your claims, especially (3) or (4)?